# PyTables - condition syntax - string slicing possible?

Tags: python, pytables

I naively tried this while querying a table:

`rows = [ x['title'] for x in table.where("""title[-11:] == 'string ends'""") ]`

resulting in: TypeError: 'VariableNode' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Reading up on Condition Syntax doc, there is no mention of slicing.

Am I to conclude I can only query on full strings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyTables cannot use indexes inside of queries.  This is a limitation of the operations supported in numexpr [1].  So yes, you can only query for full strings right now.  I am sure that they would welcome any pull requests.

1. http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/wiki/UsersGuide#Supported_operators

Comment: thanks for answering, but I am not quite sure what you mean with your last sentence. Is that a polite way of saying: implement it yourself? :-D  ..... I don't think I am experienced enough, I had to look up what 'pull request' means